# Best method to load balance between elasticsearch instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch instances:

```
IP1: 192.168.1.2 
IP2: 192.168.1.3
```

I am currently using python to send my data to my elasticsearch instances. 
How can I ensure that my data is not being duplicated between instances and properly cross loaded? Can this be done within python or does it have to be done via configuration of the .yml files?

Current ingestion method:

```
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(['192.168.1.2:9200', '192.168.1.3:9200'])
es.index(index='myindex', doc_type='mytype', body=doc)
```

Can this be done here such as sending a document to every other server or should I just send it to one?

Comment: How many shards are there in each node?

Comment: Not sure, I am setting up now, is there a recommendation?

Comment: By default elastic has 5 shards per index. Number of indexes depends on so many other factors, you can google it and setup as per your needs

Comment: Coming to your question, elastic has option of data nodes, client nodes and master nodes. By default same node acts as data, client and master nodes. The above given code connects to the master node and routes to appropriate shard